# Test case coverage of error in observable

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, test-coverage

I am trying to write test case for this code

```
 this.term.valueChange.switchMap(term => this._searchService.getTypeAheadServiceResults(term))
            .subscribe((results: TypeAheadResults) => {
                this.searchResponse = results;
                this.resultsVisible = true;
                this.error = false;
            }, (err) => {
                this.resultsVisible = false;
                this.error = true;
            });
```

But I am unable to cover lines in error case 
this is how I am trying

```
it('Error while service is down',done => {
spyon(component,'getTypeAheadServiceResults').and.returnValue(Observable.throw(new Error('error!'));
component.ngOnInit();
expect(component.error).toBe(true);
```

});

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I am unable to cover below line in testcases

```
this.resultsVisible = false;
 this.error = true;
```